# Permission denied when running .exe file with php

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have downloaded and extracted pdfinfo into my home folder in ubuntu 14.04. While I am able to run from the command line when ssh'ed into my server. When I run the following, I get a permission denied error:

`exec(/home/pdfinfodir/bin64/pdfinfo myfile.pdf);`

I am confused because I checked the permissions on pdfinfo and it has -rwxr-xr-x permissions. I am sure it's not the pdf file itself, since I can manipulate it with another program within php. Also, this works on my local virtual machine, but when I push it to the server, I get a permission denied error. How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: Check the directory is also readable by the user. If not do a chmod 755 /home/pdfinfodir/bin64/pdfinfo This will make it world readable.

Comment: giving access to the file isn't enough. the uid running the php code has to have access to ALL of the parent directories. otherwise it's the equivalent of a 'free, take one' display inside a locked bank vault.

Comment: Important point all of above are hinting at is that your php will be run as a user who is not necessarily your root user. So you need to check what user it is and what permissions it has to the path to pdfinfo and myfile.pdf. It may be worth putting it in the same group as your default/root user but be wary of the security overall. It may be wiser to place pdfinfo and your pdf file(s) somewhere under your webroot.

Comment: I just checked and all parent directories have three x's for permissions. Am I missing something?

Comment: I wound up solving the problem just by installing poppler-utils with apt-get, which contains the pdfinfo utility, but I'm still curious as to why I couldn't get the downloaded version's permissions to work. Does the www-data user have anything to do with it?